# Show that sequence is Cauchy? $|x_{n+1} − x_n| < r^n$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $0 ≤ r < 1$ be given and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $|x_{n+1} − x_n| < r^n$
for any $n ∈ N$. Show that the sequence is Cauchy.
My proof starts from this:
We have Cauchy's definition $\forall \epsilon>0$ $|a_n-a_m|< \epsilon $. And I write like this $||x_{n+1} − x_n| - |x_{m+1}- x_m||< ?$. And here, the problem is that it must be less than what $r^n$ or $r^m$. Maybe I start wrong?

Comment: We have $$\vert x_n - x_{n+2}\vert \leq \vert x_n -x_{n+1}\vert +\vert x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}\vert \leq r^n + r^{n+1}.$$ Try to generalize this to $\vert x_n - x_{n+m}\vert$ and see that this converges to zero for $n$ large.

Comment: 1/2 You didn't write correctly Cauchy's definition. 2/2 You are not asked to study the sequence $(|x_{n+1} − x_n|)$ but the sequence $( x_n)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I am sorry but I don't understand what you mean when say "Study the sequence"?  I write ${x_n}$ such that .....

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I don't understand how you get this equation $|_−_{+2}|≤|_−_{+1}|+|_{+1}−_{+2}|≤^+^{+1}$

Comment: You wrote $$||x_{n+1} − x_n| - |x_{m+1}- x_m||< ?,$$ as if you were trying to prove that the sequence  $(|x_{n+1} − x_n|)$ is Cauchy. That is not what you are asked to prove.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered toooooo  many times.

Comment: Or this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699077/

Comment: @ruslanMurzagaliev The proof of Banach Fixed Point Theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write correctly the definition of convergence in sense of Cauchy. It is: $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n, m \ge p, \hspace{0.2cm} |x_n - x_m| \le \epsilon$. This definition is the same as the following: $\underset{p \in \mathbb{N}}{\sup} |x_{n+p} - x_n| \to 0$ as $n \to + \infty$. That being said you have for all $p \ge 1$:

\begin{align*}
|x_{n+p} - x_n| &\le \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} |x_{n+k + 1}-x_{n+k}|\\
&\le \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} r^{n+k}\\
&= r^n\frac{1 - r^p}{1 - r}\\
&\le \frac{r^n}{1 - r}
\end{align*}

Then

$$\underset{p \in \mathbb{N}}{\sup} |x_{n+p} - x_n| \le \frac{r^n}{1 - r}$$

The right hand side of the inequality tends to $0$ as $n \to + \infty$. Which implies convergence in sense of Cauchy

Comment: This question has been asked and answered toooooo  many times.

Comment: @geetha290 maybe their answer was not clear to me!