# Given sequence $x_n , |x_{k+1}-x_k| < a^{-k} $. show sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Given sequence $x_n, |x_{k+1}-x_k| < a^{-k},   \forall k \in \mathbb{N} $. show sequence is Cauchy,where $a > 1$.

I was doing rough work where i considered $N= 40$, and $m=52$ and $n= 41$. So i got $|x_{50}-x_{41}| < 11 a^{-k}$. It seems that $|x_m-x_n| < |m-n|a^{-k}$. Now as $k \to \infty, a^{-k} \to 0 < \epsilon $

I am not sure, something feels wrong. can anyone help ?

Comment: You need to find $k$ with respect to $m$ and $n$. In fact, since $a>1$ then $a^{-m}>a^{-n}$ for $m<n$. Use the latter fact. You will obtain the proper result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699077/proving-that-x-n-n-1-infty-is-a-cauchy-sequence?rq=1 is a question that is similar

Comment: @gist076923: I have added that to the list of duplicate targets.

Answer (score 1):

Write this clearly and you will find it easier.

$$|x_k-x_{k+1}|<a^{-k}$$
$$|x_{k+1}-x_{k+2}|<a^{-(k+1)}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$|x_{k+i}-x_{k+i+1}|<a^{-(k+i)}$$

Summing these up and using triangle inequality gives

$$|x_k-x_{k+i+1}|<\sum\limits_{n=k}^{k+i} a^{-n}<\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} a^{-n}.$$

Can you take it from here?